Reflexivity of normed linear space ( or Banach space ) can be checked for closed unit balls?
Let $X$ be a normed linear space ( or Banach space ). The linear operator $J : X \to  (X^{*})^{*}$ defined by
$$ J(x)[\psi] = \psi(x) \ \operatorname{for all} x\in X , \psi \in X^{*}$$
is called the natural embedding of $X$ into $(X^*)^*$. The space $X $ is said to be reflexive provided $J(X)=(X^{*})^{*}$.
Now let $B$ be the closed unit ball of $X$, and $B^{**}$ the closed unit ball of $X^{**}$. My question is, if $J(B)=B^{**}$, then $X$ is reflexive ?   It seems that this reductibility occurs in the proof of the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem, Royden's Real Analysis, Fourth edition, Section 15.3, Theorem 8.

yes, this is a simple argument: if the unit ball of $X^{**}$ is contained in the image of the linear map $J$ then $J$ is surjective.

Yes, this follows from a more general fact that if a linear subspace $W$ of a normed space $V$ has a nonempty interior, then $W=V$. And that's because if $W$ has nonempty interior, then $W$ is open (by translations of the interior), but then $V\backslash W$ is open as well (as union of translations of $W$). And so $W$ is clopen, and so $W=V$ since normed spaces are connected.
And then the claim follows, because $J$ is linear, and so $J(X)$ is a linear subspace containing $B^{**}$ which has a nonempty interior.

Why $V \backslash W $ can be expressed as union of translations of $W$ ? You mean, $V = \bigcup_{a\in V \backslash W} a + W $?

@Plantation almost. It is $V\backslash W$ that is equal to $\bigcup_{a\in V\backslash W}a+W$, yes.

O.K. If so, doubts arise since $ a+ W$ may not be open ( Since $V$ is equipped only with normed space structure, not with topological vector space structure, the translation operator may not be homeomorphism ). How do you think about this?

@Plantation hmm? $x\mapsto a+x$ is a homeomorphism on every normed space, for every $a$. Also any norm induces a topology, these two structures are closely connected. And the topology we refer to here is the one induced from norm, not an arbitrary topology.

Yes. Normed linear space is topological vector space with respect to the topology induced by the norm ? And I found assoicated reference which seems to other proof : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Injective_Linear_Transformation_between_Normed_Vector_Spaces_sends_Closed_Unit_Ball_to_Closed_Unit_Ball_iff_Isometric_Isomorphism ( See the part that showing surjectivity ) . What is your opinion?
